# Using blankCursor in vlcj when vlc is playing

Tags: vlcj

Using the `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` of vlcj 3.2.0 the cursor can be disabled with `this.setCursorEnabled(false);` but this only works on the canvas.

If VLC is playing via vlcj, the cursor seems to become the default cursor and stays for the default VLC time (1000ms) until the cursor disappears.
Using VLC directly, the cursor time can be set to 0ms.

How can I make the cursor disappear using vlcj. Either setting time to 0ms or using `blankCursor`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the VLC "--mouse-hide-timeout=0" switch with vlcj then you can do that by overriding the media player factory arguments.

By default, the `EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent` has these factory arguments:

```
protected static final String[] DEFAULT_FACTORY_ARGUMENTS = {
    "--video-title=vlcj video output",
    "--no-snapshot-preview",
    "--quiet-synchro",
    "--sub-filter=logo:marq",
    "--intf=dummy"
};
```

The component class is designed to be sub-classed, one of the methods you can override allows you to set your own factory arguments:

```
mp = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent() {

    @Override
    protected String[] onGetMediaPlayerFactoryArgs() {
        return new String[] {
            "--video-title=vlcj video output",
            "--no-snapshot-preview",
            "--quiet-synchro",
            "--sub-filter=logo:marq",
            "--intf=dummy",
            "--mouse-hide-timeout=0"
        };
    }
};
```

Here we have added `--mouse-hide-timeout=0`.

That's a bit ugly because we have to provide the default arguments too. With vlcj 3.5.0 it's a bit easier if you want to preserve those default arguments:

```
mp = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent() {

    @Override
    protected String[] onGetMediaPlayerFactoryExtraArgs() {
        return new String[] {
            "--mouse-hide-timeout=0"
        };
    }
};
```

There may also be a much simpler way...

Make sure you call `mediaPlayer.setCursorEnabled(false)` *before* you show the window that contains your media player.

Comment: `--mouse-hide-timeout=0` works well. The `mediaPlayer.setCursorEnabled(false)` somehow only works an the frame, but not on the canvas. (I put this wrong in my start question)  I changed cursor to `blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(blankImage, new Point(0, 0), "blank");` and at the constructor `canvas.getCursor().getName()` returns "blank". So I think it is not a vlcj Problem actually.

Comment: Did you see the last comment about hiding the cursor before you show your window? If I do it after I show my window, I see a glitched pointer, otherwise it works as expected.